# What is the difference in meaning between the relative pronoun "das/den/die" and "wie"?

Tags: relative-clause

> Er versuchte, auf dem Schlachtfeld das Kind zu schützen. So gab er sein Leben. **Ein Ende, wie es** nur dieser aufrichtige Mann finden konnte ...

Does this mean:

> "An end **the like of which** only that righteous man could find."

How does it compare to saying:

> **Ein Ende, das** nur dieser aufrichtige Mann finden konnte ...

I also find it interesting that when you use *wie* as a connector, you need to place the direct object *es*{=*Ende*} – again, in a manner of speaking. I wonder why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"das" as pronoun starting a relative clause means "(exactly) which", whereas "wie" as used here means "like", as you've noticed.

So,

> Ein Ende, das nur dieser aufrichtige Mann finden konnte

Implies that it really is *this specific* end (and not a comparable one)